# Where is Lucifer in Supernatural Season 8?

Tags: supernatural

I am a very big fan of  `Supernatural`. I have watched all seasons of it, but I am confused as to what happened to Lucifer.  The last time we see his is with Sam having hallucinations of Lucifer and then Castile the hallucinations into his mind.

So where is Lucifer now in Supernatural?

Comment: Where is the actual question?  It sounds like maybe this is asking for rumors which are *off-topic* on this site.

Comment: @tylershads i cleaned up the wording, i think i figured out what he was asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lucifer is still in the hole with Michael the Arch Angel.  What you see of Lucifer in Season 7 are Sam's hallucinations due to the torture his soul took while being in the hole with Lucifer and Michael.

Sam was cured of his madness because the reborn Castiel took it into himself, healing Sam but causing himself great harm.

Answer (score 1):

You see Sam was just hallucinating due to the tortures that he went through in the cage, where Lucy is locked up with Michael!

Answer (score -3):

last episode of season 5 .lucifers in Sam and mike's in thier younger half brother. they end up in a graveyard getting ready for the Apoc fight night and Dean rolls in.he gets beat to crap.sam comes around puts together the rings and jumps in the hole with mike and lucifer in tow.